# Spring boot with react url not found issue

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot and react for my project, and I also use maven-frontend-plugin to combine react and spring boot to single project.

Here is my problem, when I start the project, I go to http://localhost:8083 and it will show the home page of my react frontend. But when I go to http://localhost:8083/login it will show 404 the page not found. How can I make all url for front end go to the react page (the api url all start with `/api`)

This is my maven-frontend-plugin

```
<plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- Use the latest released version:
                              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
                        <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>v15.4.0</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>7.3.0</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm run build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-build-folder</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/frontend/build</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WebConfig you can set the view controller forward to react.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
        registry.addViewController("/**/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}/**{spring:?!(\\.js|\\.css)$}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
    }
}
```

Comment: iamshaojin, would you have this project on Github? I am experiencing an issue similar to yours, but I am interested to view this solution in context, if possible? Thank you in advance!